Should a CharacterBody3D be the root of a character, or a child node?
I'm watching a tutorial on setting up a 3D player character in Godot, and at around 7:45, it shows CharacterBody3D as the root node.
I'm wondering if this is considered best practice, or if it would be better to use a Node3D as the root, with CharacterBody3D as a child node.
I'm new to Godot, but my understanding is that CharacterBody3D inherits all fields and methods from Node3D, which means I don't technically need a Node3D as a root. However, having a specific 2D/3D/UI node as the root (as suggested by the engine when you make a new scene) at least to me, makes the scene structure more explicit, but is this bad? Does it use more memory or does it decrease performance in some way?
Is there a best practice regarding this setup in Godot, or does it boil down to personal preference?

It is purely personal preference. When I develop in Godot I take the approach "make it work then make it better". So I would probably start structuring my scenes in the simplest way possible, e.g. using a Body as root node, then I refactor as needed. However from personal experience I can say that almost all my physical characters (boxes, enemies, platforms, etc.) all use a Body as root node and I've never encountered a situation where I had to refactor that.

"make it work then make it better" good advice, not only for Godot!

This makes alot of sense, and thank you for responding! Yes I'm even trying to use a Node3D as a root node and it seems more of a hassle to get it working the same as when you make a characterbody as a root node. I'll keep it mind that physicals things should have bodys as root nodes!
